# How to remove spaces between span elements within code element?

Tags: html, css, text, whitespace

I want to show JSX code example. I use following code:

In HTML I use div>pre>code>span tags for formatting each individual element, for showing syntax.

```
<div class="highlight">
        <pre>
          <code class="code">
            <span>const </span>
            root
            <span>=</span>
            ReactDOM
            <span>.</span>
            <span>createRoot</span>
            <span>(</span>
            document
            <span>.</span>
            <span>getElementById</span>
            <span>(</span>
            <span>'root'</span>
            <span>)</span>
            <span>)</span>
            <span>;</span>
            root
            <span>.</span>
            <span>render</span>
            <span>(</span>
            <span>
              <span>
                <span><</span>
                h1
              </span>
              <span>></span>
            </span>
            <span>Hello, World!</span>
            <span>
              <span>
                <span></</span>
                h1
              </span>
                <span>></span>
            </span>
            <span>)</span>
            <span>;</span>
          </code>
        </pre>
      </div>
```

In CSS I use: white-space and word-break properties.

```
.highlight {
  background: #eeffcc;
  border: 1px solid #e1e4e5;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  tab-size: 1.5em;
}

pre {
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.4;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 12px;
  display: block;
  overflow: auto;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

In the beginning I had just one, big white-space before code in code element. After I tried different CSS code you can my best on a screenshot below.
I tried to apply: white-space:pre to a span element. But it didn't act like I wanted.

[image: I want to make text looks like this]

[image: Now it looks like this]

Answer (score 1):

To remove spaces between span elements you have to write all tags in a single line without having spacing between them. because you are writing code in pre tag.